# Does xmllint support xpath 2.0; if so how to use operators?

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

I want to use `intersect` operator (xpath 2.0) with xmllint, but can't make it work.

Does xmllint support xpath 2.0?
I couldn't find any reference by Google or browsing libxml page http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libxml2 only supports XPath 1.0 and (with libxslt) XSLT 1.0. This info is [on the front page of libxml's site](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: It is a pity. I think the only free-license XPath/XSLT 2 library is [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, only that I think that xpath with saxon can't be used directly, either through xslt or java api... It's not problem for me to use more lengthy xpath 1.0 pattern with xmllint, thou xpath 2 seems more handy